# Service Worker - Is there anyway to know service worker has finished all background - sync tags?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Service Worker - Is there anyway to know service worker has finished all background - sync?

I have written a set of different sync tasks for service worker, but am wondering is there any way to know my SW has finished all its sync updates when it comes online from offline state?

So that I can send a single notification to user saying that all your updates are finished. In the below scenario, I just wanted to know when all the sync scenarios are completed, I want to emit a message using sendMessage.

```js
self.addEventListener("sync", function(event) {
console.log("Background Syncing started...");

  if(event.tag === 'case0-sync'){
 

  }else if(event.tag === 'case1-sync'){
   
  }else if(event.tag === 'case2-sync'){
    
  }else if(event.tag === 'case3-sync'){
   
  }else if(event.tag === 'case4-sync'){
    
  }
});
```

Comment: There is an open feature request at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2042. If that would be implemented, it would additionally be possible to call `getAll` on the exposed `Queue` object. Unfortunately it isn't. I kinda gave up on finding anything better which also works on Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`getTags()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SyncManager/getTags) method of the `SyncManager` interface should give you the info you're looking for.

```
self.addEventListener('sync', async (event) => {
  // Handle event...

  // Afterwards...
  const tags = await self.registration.sync.getTags();
  if (tags.length === 0) {
    // There are no registered tags.
  }
});
```

Comment: Beware, this does only work in Chrome, not Firefox or Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PeriodicSyncManager/getTags#browser_compatibility