# How to check if there are pending requests in workbox-background-sync?

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, background-sync

I want to show a notification in Vue, if there are pending requests in workbox-background-sync table. [This is my IndexedDB where I store all pending requests.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsyMf.png)

And this is my service-worker.js file

```
const showNotification = () => {
    self.registration.showNotification('Sync success!', {
        body: 'Queue Resolved ''',
    });
};

const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('offlineData', {
    maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60, // Retry for max of 24 Hours (specified in minutes)
    callbacks: {
        queueDidReplay: showNotification,
    },
});

const networkWithBackgroundSync = new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin],
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/\/*/, networkWithBackgroundSync, 'POST');
```

Comment: I think the same solution outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303059/service-worker-is-there-anyway-to-know-service-worker-has-finished-all-backgro/64360578#64360578 would work.

Comment: This solution is only possible in Chrome, because Safari or Mozilla not supporting getTags(). Do you have any idea how could I make it work on all browsers?

Comment: Right. If the `Queue` associated with the `BackgroundSyncPlugin` were publicly exposed, then I think you could call [`getAll()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-background-sync.Queue#getAll) on it and see if there were any entries. But it is stored in a private internal property. Could you file a feature request at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues asking for this functionality?

Comment: FYI there is an open feature request for what @JeffPosnick describes at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2042